# How to initialize a webapp in Tomcat only when the servlet is requested

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a tomcat webapp which has a dependency on another application (which will mostly not have started up when tomcat starts), so my initialization fails.

I want to know if there is a way to skip the initialization of my webapp at tomcat startup and initialize it only when my servlet gets a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**load-on-startup** Tag facilitate the servlet to **preinitialization** just remove the tag you will get **lazy loading** which you want

Answer (score 2):

By default your `servlet` will be initialised only when its first invoked, unless you stated otherwise in your `web.xml` using `load-on-startup` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `load-on-startup`. Alternatively, you can set `load-on-startup` for the dependent servlet to a higher value than that of the servlet it depends on to ensure that they'll be started in order.